# CascadeType.PERSIST does not save properly

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I assume that I made a mistake somewhere:
There are 2 entities (removed all useless fields):

**1. Player (many players -> in 1 team)**

```
@Component
@Entity
@Table(name = "player")
public class Player extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Min(0)
@Column(name = "uid")
private Integer uid;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "team_id", referencedColumnName = "team_id")
private Team team;
```

**2. Team (one team contains many players)**

```
@Component
@Entity
@Table(name = "team")
public class Team extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Min(0)
@Column(name = "team_id", unique = true)
private Integer teamId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Player> players;
```

**Edited (Test examples):**
1. In this case I will get an empty "team_id" and empty array from the fetching:

```
Team team = new Team(100, "Red");
Player p1 = new Player(4, "Aaa");
Player p2 = new Player(5, "Bbb");
team.addPlayer(p1);
team.addPlayer(p2);
store.getTeamStore().save(team);
System.out.println(store.getTeamStore().findAll());
-> [Team{id=1, teamId=100, teamAbbrev='Red', players=[]}]
```

2. The same + setTeam() method before saving:

```
...
p1.setTeam(team)
p2.setTeam(team)
store.getTeamStore().save(team);
System.out.println(store.getTeamStore().findAll());
-> [Team{id=1, teamId=100, teamAbbrev='Red', players=[Player{id=2, uid=4, name='Aaa'}, Player{id=3, uid=5, name='Bbb'}]}]
```

I'm using spring-boot latest (2.1.2.RELEASE) and H2 (1.4.197).
My issue is when I am saving:
1. If I try to save a `Player` with a `Team` - it's fine. Field `team_id` will be filled and then when I fetch it finds a team related to this player.
2. If I try to save a `Team` with some new `Players` - it is being saved, but `Players` will have `null` in the `team_id` field inside db. If I try to fetch - I will get an empty array.
3. If I remove `mappedBy` from the `Team` I will get new `TEAM_PLAYERS` table and fetching will work correct (I thinkg it's wrong; `team_id` will stay `null`).

What did I miss?

Comment: `Team` or `team` ?? (a small but significant difference ... "mappedBy" should match variable name ...but I am not sure, whether this is only a typo in your post or copy&paste..)

Comment: Thanks that you noticed, but there is from the copy-paste. In fact variable is a "team" as it should be.

Comment: rgr! :) ...bt, then the issue is more complicated/unclear .. :-/ (for me, at least)

Comment: Added test examples to make it more clear.

Comment: please try: `nullable="false"`on both columns (`team_id` ... if this complies with "business logic"))

Comment: `nullable="false"` does not help and also it is against the "business logic". I think that my problem could be from [unidirectional](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Unidirectional_OneToMany,_No_Inverse_ManyToOne,_No_Join_Table_(JPA_2.x_ONLY)) because if I save a Player with the Team it's fine, and it's not if I save Team with the Player. I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have your Team mapped to "team_id" in your Player class, but your @Id property is "id". change it from:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "team_id", referencedColumnName = "team_id")
private Team team;
```

To:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Team team;
```

Comment: This is not an error and it does not help (already tried this way). I made second `id` on purpose + made it unique. Even if I remove first `id` column and add `@Id` to the `team_id` nothing changes.